# Div not centering correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, center

I have an inline JS element (a countdown timer) that I need centered. But when I use text-align:center and width:100% it streches over the entire page with 25% space between each, rather than actual center.

The way I actually need it to center is like this: http://prnt.sc/b8v9fv (with equal space on left and right side). Any idea what I should be looking at to fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/gnj8nLre/

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>onepageskiw</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="forsidediv">
<img id="forsidepic" src="forsidepic.png">
</div>

<div id="overskrift">
<h1>EVENTET STARTER OM</h1>
</div>

<div id="countdowner">
<table id="table">
<tr>
<div id="countdown">
<td id="id1"></td>
<td id="id2"></td>
<td id="id3"></td>
<td id="id4"></td>
</div>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="timeLabel">Days</td>
<td class="timeLabel">Hours</td>
<td class="timeLabel">Mins</td>
<td class="timeLabel">Secs</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>
CountDownTimer('06/25/2016 10:00 AM', 'id');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id)
{
    var end = new Date(dt);

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById(id+"1").innerHTML = days;
        document.getElementById(id+"2").innerHTML = hours;
        document.getElementById(id+"3").innerHTML = minutes;
        document.getElementById(id+"4").innerHTML = seconds;
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
margin:0;   
}

h1  {
position:absolute;  
width:100%;
text-align:center;
margin:0;
color:black;
font-family:Helvetica;
}

#countdowner {
color:black;
position:absolute;
margin:0;
margin-top:1em;
padding:0;
width:100%;
font-size:2em;
font-family:Helvetica;
}

#table {
width:100%;
text-align:center;  
}

#forsidediv {
position:fixed;
text-align: center;
bottom:0;
}

#forsidepic {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Tables for layout? Perhaps you should consider using flexbox. It can do what you intend to already.

Comment: I would also run your HTML through a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers. Im still very much a beginner, and this is my first time working with styling a Javascript element. I will however look up flexbox and see how it works. :)

Also thanks for the validator link, I did not know about that site. It seems though I have a fatal error I have to look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `width:100%;` from `#table` and add `margin:0 auto;` then add some padding to tds

```
#table {
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}

#table td{
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gnj8nLre/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/c2229s5g/

I only changed the CSS for `#table` and added:

```
#table {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

That way I made it a flexbox parent, with all its children being centered in the line. Actually I would also change the HTML a bit(removing all table stuff and putting a wrapper around counter and label elements), but it also already works with this little change.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into what flexbox is. This assignment is for an exam and I have to be able to explain my code, and right now this is my first time hearing of flexbox. :)